# sql integrity constraint parent key not found

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am trying to do something so simple creating and insert 4 tables with their data. I have spent hours on the web researching integrity constraints and tried several IDE's in case there's a bug but nothing seems to work. Code is shows below (excuted in order).

I can insert the data for the first two tables i.e vod_actor and vod_classification but when trying to add third/fourth table data I get the following error: 
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.VOD_FILM_CLASS_FK) violated - parent

I don't understand why because the FK for vod_film is the PK for vod_classification which already has its data populated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a beginner please bear that in mind. Thanks

```
     CREATE TABLE vod_actor (
     dbActorId      CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
     dbFirstname    VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
     dbLastname     VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
     dbDateOfBirth  DATE,
     dbNationality  VARCHAR2(30),
     dbBiography    CLOB,
     CONSTRAINT vod_actor_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbActorId)
     );

     CREATE TABLE vod_classification (
     dbClassId  CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
     dbDescription  VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT vod_classification_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbClassId)
     );

     CREATE TABLE vod_film (
     dbFilmId   CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
     dbTitle        VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
     dbDirector_firstname   VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
     dbDirector_lastname    VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
     dbGenre        VARCHAR2(20),
     dbUK_release_date  DATE,
     dbFilename     VARCHAR2(50),
     dbRuntime  NUMBER(4),
     dbClass        CHAR(3),
     CONSTRAINT vod_film_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbFIlmId),
     CONSTRAINT vod_film_class_FK FOREIGN KEY (dbClass) REFERENCES
     vod_classification (dbClassId) ON DELETE SET NULL
     );

     CREATE TABLE vod_role (
     dbFilmId           Char(4) NOT NULL,
     dbActorId          CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
     dbCharacterName    VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
     dbFirstAppearance  NUMBER(6),
     dbDescription      CLOB,
     CONSTRAINT vod_role_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbFilmId, dbActorId, dbCharacterName),
     CONSTRAINT vod_role_film_FK FOREIGN KEY (dbFilmId) REFERENCES vod_film (dbFilmId)
     ON DELETE CASCADE,
     CONSTRAINT vod_role_actor_FK FOREIGN KEY (dbActorId) REFERENCES         vod_actor (dbActorId)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
     );

     //Insert into vod_actor & vod_classification works fine
```

Executing code below gives the error:

```
     INSERT INTO vod_film VALUES ('1', 'Toy Story 3', 'Lee', 'Unkrich', 'Comedy', '19-JUL-2010', 'ToyStory3.mpg', '103', 'U');

     INSERT INTO vod_film VALUES ('2', 'Lord of the Rings: Fellowship of the ring', 'Peter', 'Jackson', 'Fantasy', '19-DEC-2001', 'Fellowship.mpg', '178', '12');

     INSERT INTO vod_film VALUES ('3', 'Lord of the Rings: Two Towers', 'Peter', 'Jackson', 'Fantasy', '18-DEC-2002', 'TwoTowers.mpg', '179', '12');

     INSERT INTO vod_film VALUES ('4', 'Lord of the Rings: Return of the King', 'Peter', 'Jackson', 'Fantasy', '17-DEC-2003', 'KingReturns.mpg', '201', '12');

     INSERT INTO vod_film VALUES ('5', 'Face/Off', 'John', 'Woo', 'Action', '7-NOV-1997', 'FaceOff.mpg', '138', '18');

     INSERT INTO vod_film VALUES ('6', 'The Nutty Professor', 'Tom', 'Shadyac', 'Comedy', '4-OCT-1996', 'NuttyProf.mpg', '95', '12');
```

Comment: Can you show the data from the `vod_classification` table?

Comment: Can you execute `select dbClassId from vod_Classification where dbClassID in ('U','12','18')` and show the results?  Do all 6 inserts fail or just some? if some which?  It may be that vod_Classification while appearing to have U,12,18 may have space or non-display characters which is causing the error  such as ' U' or '12 ' or '18'+char(13)+char(10)  If you have the inserts for vod_Classification show the ones for IDs, U,12, and 18.

Comment: Why is vod_Classification.dbclassID char(4) while vod_Film.dbclass char(3)? seems like they should be the same if PK/FK...  and being char data, I would think spaces would be at the end thus 'U' would be 'U   ' (3 spaces in vod) while in Vod_film it would be 'U  ' U with 2 spaces...  that alone would cause the PK/FK to fail.  different char lengths on the data types.

Comment: Data in vod_classification table: INSERT INTO vod_classification (dbClassId, dbDescription) VALUES ('U', 'Universal: Suitable for all');

INSERT INTO vod_classification (dbClassId, dbDescription) VALUES ('PG', 'Parental Guidance: General viewing but some scenes may be unsuitable for young ...');

INSERT INTO vod_classification (dbClassId, dbDescription) VALUES ('12', 'Suitable only for persons of 12 yrs...');

INSERT INTO vod_classification (dbClassId, dbDescription) VALUES ('15', 'Suitable ...');

INSERT INTO vod_classification (dbClassId, dbDescription) VALUES ('18', 'Suitable ...');

Comment: also executing select dbClassId from vod_Classification where dbClassID in ('U','12','18') gives me correct results 12, 18, U

Comment: @xQbert That worked!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this case different character lengths for the PK FK fields I think is the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE vod_classification (
     dbClassId  CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
     ....

CREATE TABLE vod_film (
...
     dbClass        CHAR(3),
```

Given constraint

```
 CONSTRAINT vod_film_class_FK FOREIGN KEY (dbClass) REFERENCES
     vod_classification (dbClassId)
```

Appear to be the issue.  char(3) <>  char(4)  make them both the same. likely the 3 to 4.

If I remember right char pads spaces to the end so 'U  ' will never equal 'U   ' U w/ 2 spaces for 3 characters vs U with 3 spaces for 4 characters.  One of the reasons I prefer varchar no padding of spaces.  Why was char chosen here?

Comment: Tables were provided as part of a tutoral exercise. Thanks.